# javascript save file from http response (Web Api HttpResponseMessage)

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs

So i have a problem when i tried to save file from server response.

When i try to download the file from url in my browser all work but when i tried to send request from the clint side the file is saved but in the file there is "[Object object]" and if it's a PDF file does not open.

The request must include an additional header that contains the key ID of the client.

Here my server code :

```
        [HttpGet, IsAllowed(4,PageAction.Download)]
    public HttpResponseMessage Download(string id)
    {
        var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + string.Format(@"Files\{0}.doc",id);
        var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");            
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = string.Format("{0}.doc", id);
        return result;
    }
```

And here my clint code :

```
 function get() {
    var defer = $q.defer();

    $http.post('http://localhost:4704/api/file/download/1', { responseType: 'arrayBuffer' }).then(
        function (data, status, headers, config) {
            var results = {
                data: data,
                headers: data.headers(),
                status: data.status,
                config: data.config
            };
            defer.resolve(results);

        }, function (data, status, headers, config) {
            defer.reject(data);
        });
    return defer.promise;
}


$scope.download = function () {

    get().then(function (response) {
        var octetStreamMime = 'application/octet-stream';
        var fileName = "Test.doc";
        var contentType = response.headers["content-type"] || octetStreamMime;
        try {
            var blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: contentType });
            if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
            } else {
                var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                window.open(objectUrl);
            }
        } catch (exc) {
            console.log("Save Blob method failed with the following exception.");
            console.log(exc);
        }

    }, function (error) {

    });
```

In addition, I also tried the following code:

```
    $http.get("http://localhost:4704/api/file/download").then(function (res) {
        var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
        anchor.attr({
            href: 'data:attachment/doc;charset=utf-8,',
            target: '_blank',
            download: 'test.doc'
        })[0].click();
    })
```

Comment: if you are trying to download a file . ur header must have **content-type:multipart/form-data** . If you are not able to open the pdf file properly, it means that the stream is affected. so you need to figure out in the conversions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server code is clearly sending binary data in response to an HTTP GET from the client. In that case the client needs to set the XHR to `responseType: arraybuffer`.

**Example HTML**

```
<button ng-click="fetch()">Get file</button>

<a download="{{filename}}" xd-href="data">
  <button>SaveAs {{filename}}</button>
</a>
```

The HTML creates two buttons. Clicking the first button gets the file from the server. The second button saves the file.

**`xd-href` Directive**

```
app.directive("xdHref", function() {
  return function linkFn (scope, elem, attrs) {
     scope.$watch(attrs.xdHref, function(newVal) {
       newVal && elem.attr("href", newVal);
     });
  };
});
```

The directive watches the scope property defined by the `xd-href` attribute and sets the `href` attribute to the value of that scope property.

**Controller**

```
var url = "http://localhost:4704/api/file/download/1";
$scope.fetch = function() {
     $http.get(url, {responseType: "arraybuffer"})
       .then (function (response) {
         var disposition = response.headers("content-disposition");
         var filename = disposition.match(/filename="(\w*.\w*)"/)[1];
         $scope.filename = filename || "f.bin";
         $scope.data = new Blob([response.data]);
     }).catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
         throw error;
     });
};
```

The controller uses an XHR GET method to fetch the file, extracts the filename from the `Content-Disposition` header, and creates a blob from the response data. It sets `download` attribute of the `<a>` tag to the value of the file name and the `href` attribute to the value of the blob. Clicking on the `<a>` will cause the browser to open a save dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is in json format you can use this

```
href: 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + JSON.stringify(data)
```

or you can also use this to encode your data,try this

```
href: 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data)
```