# How to save file from api

Tags: angular, api, file, download

I'm new in angular and I need to know how to save file from my API on a user computer. In my API, I have DownloadController with `downloadChapter` method on /download/chapter/{id}. When I call this method from Chrome, my computer just start downloading the chapter file - and it's ok. When I call this method form my DownloadService in angular I get the error in console: ERROR OK.

My download chapter method:

```
  downloadChapter(id: number): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.http
      .get<Blob>(`${this.basicPath}/chapter/${id}`)
      .pipe(
        tap((res) => {
            console.log(`response: ${res}`);
          },
          (e) => {
            console.log(`error: ${e} - ???`);
          }, () => {
            console.log('win!');
          }),
      );
  }
```

In API response:

> 200 OK OK,URL
>   [file:/Users/lukasz/Workspace/Inz/api/booky/uploads/1/6:Solaris%20-%20Maly%20Apokryf.mp3],[Content-Disposition:"attachment;filename=6:Solaris%20-%20Maly%20Apokryf.mp3", Content-Type:"audio/mpeg", Content-Length:"97857000"]

How to fix it? I want to just save the file on a user computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript save file from http response (Web Api HttpResponseMessage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40958253/javascript-save-file-from-http-response-web-api-httpresponsemessage)

Comment: take a look at `https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an angular 6 example of downloading file from a restful api:

Install file saver:
`npm install file-saver --save`

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

.
.
.
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

download() {
    this.http.get('/download/chapter/{id}', {responseType:'blob', observe: 'response'}).subscribe(
      (data : any)=>{
        saveAs(data.body, 'yourfilename.ext');
      },
      (err : HttpErrorResponse)=>{
        console.error('download failed:', err);
      });
}

.
.
.
```